# Convert all headings X into headings X + 1 or heading X - 1 in Google Documents

Tags: google-docs

Is a way to convert all headings X into headings X + 1 or heading X - 1 in Google Documents?

E.g. I have a Google document with 100 headings 2: is there any way to convert them into headings 1 or 3 in a convenient fashion (i.e. without having to manually change the heading for each 100 of them)?

Comment: Basically - no.
Unless you want some convoluted way of doing it.

Answer (score 17):

With this little script you can change the headings automatically. Especially useful when the different headings are convoluted.

### Code

```
function changeHeading() {
  var pars = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs();  
  for(var i in pars) {
    var p = pars[i], h = p.getHeading(), d = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading;
    switch(h) {
      case h.HEADING1:
        p.setHeading(d.HEADING2);
        break;
      case h.HEADING2:
        p.setHeading(d.HEADING1);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

### Explained

First all paragraph types are collected. Then these are checked for headings. If a heading matches *Heading 1*, then it's changed to *Heading 2* etc.

Add this script in your Google Document under *Tools > Script editor...*. Press the "bug" button to authenticate the script.

Comment: The above script has a bug in it. It changes all existing Heading 1 to Heading 2 and it changes all existing heading 2 to Heading 1, when it should be Heading 3. This version just swaps Heading 1 and Heading two instead of pushing everything down a level.

Comment: @AugustMohr I thought the OP meant heading 1 or 3. You can alter the script anyway you like to see for yourself.

Comment: With newer version of Google Docs, the process is a little different. You first need to use `Extensions -> Apps Script`. In the new window you need to create the script, paste it, save it and run it. More or less. It worked.

Answer (score 13):

I figured out a  work-around when I was copying text from another Google Doc that already had h1, h2, etc that didn't fit into the target document.

If you highlight text, in the right-click menu, there is "Select all matching text". This selects all text with the same formatting in the document. For instance, if you select an H2 text, it will select all H2 texts. If you select bolded, italicized text, it will select all bolded, italicized text.

First, what I needed to do was cut the copied text and paste it into a new document. That's because I didn't want to select H1s in the whole document; I just want the H1 in the copied text. So I needed the copied text alone in another document.

Then, in that new document, I selected an H1, right-clicked, and selected "Select all matching text". This highlighted all the H1s in the copied text. I changed them to H3 with `ctrl+alt+3`, which is what I needed them to be in the new document. Same deal with H2s, demoting them to H4s.

Then I cut and pasted the demoted text back into the target document. Done!

Comment: This is the answer! No scripting necessary. user4160 convoluted it though by talking about his situation instead of the OP's. To answer the OP's question: highlight the 1 of the headings that's currently styled as Heading 2, right click, click `Select all matching text`, click Heading 2 in the menu bar, select the desired heading (e.g. Heading 1 or Heading 3). Done.

Comment: Note that if you're incrementing all the headings you have to change the highest numbered ones first, otherwise the you won't be able to select them without selecting the ones you already incremented. E.g., h3's need to become h4's before h2's become h3's. (If you're decrementing you have to do the lower numbered ones first.)

Answer (score 6):

After a couple of days of more 'normal' activity levels no better offer yet so I suggest:

Change "Heading 2" to the required style and then "Update 'Heading 2' to match.

This does not add or subtract from the Heading reference number but at least allows easy propagation across the 100 headings to be changed, by altering one only.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following two scripts to increase or decrease the heading levels.

```
function decreaseHeadingLevel() {
  var pars = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs();  
  for(var i in pars) {
    var p = pars[i], h = p.getHeading(), d = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading;
    switch(h) {
      case h.TITLE:
        p.setHeading(d.HEADING1);
        break;
      case h.HEADING1:
        p.setHeading(d.HEADING2);
        break;
      case h.HEADING2:
        p.setHeading(d.HEADING3);
        break;
      case h.HEADING3:
        p.setHeading(d.HEADING4);
        break;
      case h.HEADING4:
        p.setHeading(d.HEADING5);
        break;
      case h.HEADING5:
        p.setHeading(d.HEADING6);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

```
function increaseHeadingLevel() {
  var pars = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs();  
  for(var i in pars) {
    var p = pars[i], h = p.getHeading(), d = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading;
    switch(h) {
      case h.HEADING1:
        p.setHeading(d.TITLE);
        break;
      case h.HEADING2:
        p.setHeading(d.HEADING1);
        break;
      case h.HEADING3:
        p.setHeading(d.HEADING2);
        break;
      case h.HEADING4:
        p.setHeading(d.HEADING3);
        break;
      case h.HEADING5:
        p.setHeading(d.HEADING4);
        break;
      case h.HEADING6:
        p.setHeading(d.HEADING5);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If more configurability (e.g. shifting by X) is needed, here's a small
script that allows shifting by an arbitrary X value (e.g. if X=2, Heading 3 -> Heading 1). Provides edge case handling for when the desired offset would "break" the current heading tree in the document.

Should be easily adaptable for the opposite use case of shifting down (e.g. Header 3 -> 4). Some minor improvements can be made algorithmically to make more efficient, but should be negligible improvements for common document editing cases.

```
function shiftUp() {
  // Shift X for each header.
  const OFFSET = 1;

  var pars = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs();  
  var headings = [
    DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1,
    DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2,
    DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3,
    DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING4,
    DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING5,
  ];
  var minIdx = headings.length;
  for(var i in pars) {
    var p = pars[i], h = p.getHeading();
    var headingIdx = headings.indexOf(h);
    if (headingIdx > -1){
        minIdx = Math.min(minIdx, headingIdx);
    }
  }

  // Avoiding upshift if the biggest header is smaller than the desired offset.
  if (minIdx <= -1 + OFFSET) {
    console.log("Not shifting as target offset is greater than the biggest header, which would break the header tree");
    return
  }

  // Updating headers.
  for(var i in pars) {
    var p = pars[i], h = p.getHeading();
    var headingIdx = headings.indexOf(h);
    if (headingIdx > -1){
      // Set new heading with the new offset.
        p.setHeading(headings[headingIdx-OFFSET]);
    }
  }
}
```