# How to put every heading in a section to a lower tier all at once in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, google

There is this section in my document that has a lot of Heading1’s, some of them having Heading2’s and Heading3’s underneath. I would like to change all these Heading1’s into Heading2’s, Heading2’s into Heading3’s, and Heading3’s into Heading4’s, so that I can add a Heading1 in front of all of them to group them into a section.

How can I do this automatically, or can I only manually change them one by one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert all headings X into headings X + 1 or heading X - 1 in Google Documents](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/71290/convert-all-headings-x-into-headings-x-1-or-heading-x-1-in-google-documents)